# Contentful: Configure Webhook Payload to Include Reference Field Properties

Tags: webhooks, contentful, contentful-management

Say I have a Content Type `Book` with a text field `Title` and a reference field `Author`, which in turn has it's own fields `Name` (text) and `Headshot` (media - image).

I want to set up a webhook that fires whenever a `Book` is created or updated, and I want the payload to include all of the fields, including the nested reference `Author` fields.

When using the Content Delivery API, I know that I can specify an `include` property to specify how many nested levels of reference fields I want returned, like so:

```
await client.getEntries({
  content_type: 'book',
  include: 2
});
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to specify something similar in the webhook payload configuration object in order to have the payload itself contain nested reference field properties, rather than just it's `sys` fields.

If this is not possible, then how should I approach requesting the nested field properties? If I do a new request with the reference's ID, is it guaranteed to exist or will I have to wait the 5 minutes it takes for the CDN changes to propagate?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The references are not included in the webhook payload and you will have to make a separate request based on the id of the reference field.

If can't wait for the CDN to propagate (which should only take at most a minute) you could always query the reference through the management API. Remember though that the management API calls are more costly as they are not cached. If possible I would suggest waiting until the CDN propagation has completed and query the reference at that time.

Comment: Thanks Robban, that makes sense. The waiting solution gets complicated when the webhook is supposed to trigger a serverless function so I'll probably go the content management route.